# XSLT code to remove xml tag

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming XML like below: I need to remove the `<shoeboxImage>` tag from the incoming below XML.

Incoming XML Input:

```
<attachReceipt>
   <baseMessage>
      <returnCode>200</returnCode>
   </baseMessage>
   <payload>
      <returnCode>0</returnCode>
      <shoeboxItem>
         <shoeboxImageCount>2</shoeboxImageCount>
         <shoeboxImages>
            <shoeboxImage>
               <name>receiptImage.jpg</name>
            </shoeboxImage>
            <shoeboxImage>
               <name>receiptImage.jpg</name>
            </shoeboxImage>
         </shoeboxImages>
      </shoeboxItem>
   </payload>
</attachReceipt>
```

Expected Output:

```
<attachReceipt>
   <baseMessage>
      <returnCode>200</returnCode>
   </baseMessage>
   <payload>
      <returnCode>0</returnCode>
      <shoeboxItem>
         <shoeboxImageCount>2</shoeboxImageCount>
         <shoeboxImages>
            <name>receiptImage.jpg</name>
            <name>receiptImage.jpg</name>
         </shoeboxImages>
      </shoeboxItem>
   </payload>
</attachReceipt>
```

Need some xslt code snippet to do this.

Comment: I don't see a question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the necessary software installed to actually test this, but this should work:

```
<xsl:template match="shoeboxImage">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The idea is that when a `shoeboxImage` element is encountered, it generates nothing for the element itself, and just continues with its children.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an identity template and a template that will remove the element `shoeboxImage` but will retain its descendants.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template override for the element shoeboxImage -->
    <xsl:template match="shoeboxImage">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```